# Electron child window doesn't want to call its own js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm very much not a javascript person, but I've been making an Electron GUI, and I'm getting confused by why I can't seem to make a child browser window call its own js.

I have a main.js that does a bunch of things, setting up a tray menu, one option of which will spawn a browser window like this:

```
  window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 360,
    height: 320,
    backgroundColor: "#D6D8DC",
    show: false
  })

  window.setMenuBarVisibility(false);

  window.loadURL(require('url').format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))
```

And that window loads fine, and includes this reference to its own `window.js`, which is the way I've seen it done in Electron examples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Radiam Agent</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
        <h3>Username</h3>
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text" size="40"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
        <h3>Password</h3>
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="40"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/>

    <div class="button">
      <button id="login">Get Radiam Login Token</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="window.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But the `window.js` code, which looks like this (the entire file), doesn't seem to fire ever:

```
const notifier = require("node-notifier");
const zerorpc = require("zerorpc");
let client = new zerorpc.Client();
client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");

function login(event) {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  client.invoke("login", username, password, function(error, res, more) {
    if (res){
      notifier.notify({"title" : "Radiam", "message" : res});
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", login(event));
})
```

Am I missing something? Again, not a js person (I'm building a GUI to a Python script, which is otherwise working great), but it seems like it should be obvious...

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the index.html completely

Comment: Your js code interacts with your HTML, so we very much need to see your HTML for the page.

Comment: On paper that setup should work. Are you sure that `window.js` isn't throwing an error before your event handler is set?

Comment: I'm not, that's the thing! I'm just running this with npm start, I'm wondering if I'm missing some logging or something.

Comment: Wrap your entire `window.js` module into a try/catch statement and see what happens.

Comment: still nothing! totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

This worked. I think it was the wrong type of listener, plus I shouldn't have been trying to pass `event`:

```
const notifier = require("node-notifier");
const zerorpc = require("zerorpc");
let client = new zerorpc.Client();
client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");

function login() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  client.invoke("login", username, password, function(error, res, more) {
    if (res){
      notifier.notify({"title" : "Radiam", "message" : res});
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", login);
```